# AWS SQS : After sending a message, is it possible to know if it was duplicate

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am sending a message to an AWS SQS que as below -

```
Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
headers.put("message-group-id", messageGroup);
headers.put("message-deduplication-id", "000001");
queueMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("Que-Name", msgObject, headers, postProcessor);
```

After the first message, subsequent messages are ignored as duplicate as expected because of duplicate deduplication id.

But, I would like to somehow know that it was ignored. Is there a way? I implemented the PostProcessor hoping that the Message object would have an attribute giving some information to that effect. But, it doesn't seem to have anything useful.

Comment: I can't see anything (eg logs) that would be able to tell you that a duplicate was discarded.

Comment: SQS returns the same message-id as the earlier message when the message is duplicate; you can store the message-id in the cache or any other storage and compare; if SQS is not returning any flag that suggests that message was duplicate